# Looking for Mac Applications like IOGraph

Tags: macos, software-rec, mouse

Anyone know of apps similar to IOGraph by IOGraphica?

Basically this app tracks your mouse movements and makes art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the self-explanatorily titled (and equally useless) [Mouse Distance Measurer](http://alphaomega.software.free.fr/mousedistancemeasurer/Mouse%20Distance%20Measurer.html).

[image]